# Increase Number Size in Charts

Tags: css, qliksense

I'm doing a report using Qliksense but when using a proyector you can barely see the numbers on the graphs.

Any ideas on how to modify the code of the program to increase number/text size overall?

Answer (score 1):

A possible way to do that would be to use the themes in QlikSense. Yet they have limited functionality, but they may be able to help in your case.

You will have to go into your QlikSense themes directory, mine is under `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Qlik\Sense\Client\themes`. Here you will find the default themes (you can also create your own ones).

Create a copy of the folder `sense` which is the default theme (let's name this new folder `senseModif` from now on). Open the file `theme.json` from the new directory and play around with the values. For example if you want to set text sizes in a pie chart you can modify this segment:

```
"pieChart": {
    ...
    "item": {
        "name": {
            "fontSize": {
                "default": "50px",
                "large": "50px",
                "medium": "50px",
                "small": "50px",
                "tiny": "50px"
            },
            ...
```

I already changed the `fontSize` values here for 50px. To see the result of this just go to the QS web interface, open your app, and open a sheet in it. You will have a similar url for the app: `http://localhost:4848/sense/app/filenameofapp.qvf/sheet/GPUNXF/state/analysis/`. Now just put `theme/senseModif` at the end of the url and it will now display the objects with your new styles.

As I said, at least for me, it's not working for every object type right now, but at least it's a start.

Much more on the themes and on their usage can be found [here](https://community.qlik.com/docs/DOC-13517).

Comment: I will try this and let you know! Thanks